# GCM Implementation using PHP always facing Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I am always getting 401 error.Please any one could let me know exactly what should be HTTP referrers if i am using my local server. i.e Currently I am using:

```
    http://localhost/GCM/index.php
```

and generating a API access key using it.

Here is my php code for GCM request.

```
                $key='mykey';
                $headers=array('Contenttype:application/json','Authorization:key='.$key);
                $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
                $ch = curl_init();
                $curlConfig = array(
                CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
                CURLOPT_POST           => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode(array('field1' => 'some date','field2' => 'some other data',)),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                );
                curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                if($result==FALSE){
                    echo curl_error($ch);
                    echo curl_getinfo($ch);
                }else{
                    echo $result;
                }
```

Answer (score 8):

I battled same problem. Turned out it was IPv6 related! I created server key as described in http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html using **0.0.0.0/0** as permitted host IP, but that does not match IPv6. So I added another permitted host line IP as **0::0/0** and that worked (AFTER some time, to update cached config?).

Leaving the IP field blank allows ANY IP and is easier.

Comment: hey thanks... leaving IP address blank is the best solution... u solved my problem...

Comment: Leaving the IP field blank solved my problem. Thanks. It saved my day

Comment: The IPv6 was my problem.  after adding 0::0/0 to the ip list it worked great.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I can see several errors:

1. `Contenttype:application/json` should be `Content-Type: application/json`.
2. You forgot to include the registration ids in the JSON.
3. I'm not sure if `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false` are required.

You can find many PHP GCM samples that work (for example - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)).

Comment: Thanks Eran after correcting headers its working fine after. But I am generating authentication key using "Any IP allowed". which is a security issue.And still after generating key from "http://localhost/GCM/index.php" or http://<server-ip>/GCM/index.php getting same 401 error.

Comment: Hello @user2173085 you got the solution for this? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to you are not enable you IP to access GCM,To Know your network IP type "**my ip**" in GOOGLE,after that create **SERVER KEY** in you Google_Api_Console and Use the ip in **SERVER KEY** generation,Use the **SERVER KEY** in your php file in local server,the first image show's the list of key in google console to select,choose server key and second image show's that to put the ip what you need to enable.

[image: IMG1] [image: IMG2]