# GCM http 401 authorization error

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, http-status-code-401

When my backend server sends post requests to GCM servers I get an authorization error HTTP 401.

I followed the steps described here:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error

```
>> api_key=AIzaSyDEy3...

>> curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_id\":\"ABC\"}"
```

I get this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In the troubleshooting it says:

```
Authentication Error
The sender account that you're trying to use to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Possible causes are:
    1. Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax.
    2. Invalid project number sent as key.
    3. Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
    4. Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.
```

I have questions about that:

1. Is the header in the curl request correct?
2. Do they mean "api_key" (AIzaSy…) or the Project number like 8305134….?
3. How do I whitelist my Server Key IP?
4. If I'm running the curl command, do I have to whitelist the IP-Address of my computer?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21628030/1765530

Comment: For others who are browsing just now, if you've suddenly started experiencing this error without making any specific changes (the Server Key) still the same, you probably need to import your project to Firebase. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801206/4625829).

Answer (score 28):

> Do they mean "api_key" (AIzaSy…) or the Project number like 8305134….?

It means Server key which should added in your curl script. The project number should not be used for sending message on server side.
 
 
To create the new server key, follow the steps,

- Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/project
- Click your Project
- Go to **APIs & auth** on Left Panel
- Select Credentials in submenu on Left Panel
- Under **Public API access**, click on "**Create New Key**"
- Choose 'Server'
- On next dialog, Specify the whitelisted IPs, if you have any. Leaving it blank, the requests will be from any IP
- Click **Create**.
- You will find the new server key is created under "**Public API Access**"

This key is to be used for sending message in your script on server side.

> How do I whitelist my Server Key IP?

You can whitelist while creating server key.

> If I'm running the curl command, do I have to whitelist the IP-Address of my computer?

For testing purpose, you dont have to specify the IP. For commercial purpose, you may want to.

**Warning** setting IP to **0.0.0.0/0** as mentioned in the *Getting Started* guide will allow all IPv4 address, but not IPv6.

Comment: I also had to activate both Chrome and Android Cloud Messaging API's.

Comment: +1, Thanks @vijay-c Initialy I used the **Android Application API Key** in the server. So i got 401 unauthorized error. From your answer only I come to know we need to generate and use the **Server Application API Key**.

Comment: Can you update with latest screens of https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects? Seems it is been modified and i couldn't find the specified menu's.!

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE:**

Google has changed the console, now you have to:

- Go to https://console.developers.google.com
- Select your project (dropdown at top)
- Select **Overview** in menu on Left Panel
- Select **Google Cloud Messaging** under **Mobile APIs** title
- Click **Enable** button
- Then you have to create the credentials

**DEPRECATED**

I had the same problem ... then I realized that I had to add the **Google Cloud Messaging for Android** too.

- Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/project
- Click your Project
- Go to **APIs & auth** on Left Panel
- Select **APIs** in submenu on Left Panel
- Search **Google Cloud Messaging for Android (or/and Chrome)** and put it ON

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It works for me. I had the same problem with Parse.com and it's Push Notifications mechanism.

Answer (score 17):

I solved this error by using the Server Key instead of the API Key. You can get the Server Key from Firebase Console by clicking on the gear and clicking on Project Settings, after that go to the tab that says Cloud Messaging and get the server key, both the normal server key and the legacy server key will work.

This works on both Firebase and GCM so we do not need to declare two keys separately.

Answer (score 11):

Finally found My problem

> I made HTTP Authorization Header like this `Authorization:[Api key]`
>
> Solution
>
> I was missing 'key='+[Your Api key] in the Authorization header,

so the full HTTP header will be

> `Authorization:key=Apikey`

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I was using the **Android Key** as mentioned in the instructions at 
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
But I actually had to use the **Server Key** to get authenticated from my Fiddler window and PushSharp example.

Comment: Absolutely right, it must be *Server Key* for me too

Comment: Yeah it works. So strange that my Android Key still worked in the last couple of months until today.

Comment: @QuanNguyen, My android key had worked for me in the past too.

Comment: @Vijay Vepakomma, Can you tell m whats the difference in Android vs Server key ?

Comment: @user1324887 Android key is used by the app to send its notification to the OS, server key is for authenticating it to the push notification server

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't know the syntax of the `curl` command, but it seems strange that one header you specify as `--header "key: value"` while the other is specified as `--header key:"value"`. Perhaps one of them is incorrect. In addition, you should change `registration_id:ABC` to `"{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"`.
2. They mean the API Key.
3. If you didn't define a list of white listed IPs when you created your API Key, it should be white listed by default.

Comment: Been trying to deploy and configure GCM, your answer was the only one that helped me. Basically I've been trying to test using the curl commands but I was always spitting out "Unauthorized". That page was the first to give me a valid response, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. What I did is:

1. Clear IP Whitelist that will be set to Any IP automatically.
2. Regenerate Server Key and use the new generated Key.

Comment: For me clearing the list of ip's worked. I did not have to re-generate my server key.0.0.0.0/0 does not work. I don't know why they have mentioned to add it in the documentation? How will GCM know that the request is coming from my desktop and not any actual server.

Answer (score 2):

If you have recently tried to create a new project in GCM and add a server key, it won't succeed authorization anyway because Google stopped authorizing newly created server keys in order to promote Firebase Cloud Messaging. Currently the only option to create a new key is to first migrate the existing project to Firebase [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

Answer (score 2):

if error 401:  the GCM has to be imported in FCM to work
Then the server and sender IDs can be found at
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my_projectID/settings/cloudmessaging

Answer (score 0):

Unauthorised issue will happen while there is a mismatch in API key.
Clear the server key and regenerate a new one. Use the server API key in server side coding. And properly use the sender id in android client

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to authorization, but I came across this, error while I was trying to do things in old way,
I know this is an old question, but let me put my 50 cents on it.
First there is a new kid in town called "Firebase Cloud Messaging FCM". Allow me to quote google:

> FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits
> GCM’s core infrastructure, with new SDKs to make Cloud Messaging
> development easier.
>
> Benefits of upgrading to FCM SDK include:
>
> Simpler client development. You no longer have to write your own
> registration or subscription retry logic. An out-of-the-box
> notification solution. You can use Firebase Notifications, a
> serverless notifications solution with a web console that lets anyone
> send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase
> Analytics insights.
> [More information about FCM](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm)
> [Configuration For android studio](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#android)

I hope this helps someone who is trying to do things in old way

Answer (score 0):

For using `Firestore` you should use `Web API key`firebase console gives you, which you can find at
`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<yourProjectName>/settings/general/<yourAppPckageName>`.

but, for using `Firebase` to push notification your mobile device clients you should use `Server key` developer console gives you, which you can find at
`https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<yourProjectName>`

Answer (score -1):

The above things are all done then check curl init operation the function 

`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );`

is included or not if it is not then include the function