# Android: Send a Notification to Cordova PhoneGap Application

Tags: android, cordova, curl, push-notification

I'm learning to use PhoneGap.
I want to send a notification to all the users of my app

For that I have register into https://console.developers.google.com and created my app.

I have the `API_KEY`
the `PROJECT_NUMBER` which looks like: `XXXXXXXXXXXX`

I have added to my phonegap app the plugin with

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="<PROJECT_NUMBER>"
```

It seems that the plugin is correctly installed. And I dont know how to go through. I know I can make a curl to send a notification, but how should it be?

Could anyone provide a curl example to send to push notification for Android?

### EDIT

I'm sending the notification like this:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: key=<API_KEY>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{ 
"registration_ids": [ 
  "<PROJECT_NUMBER>"
], 
"data": { 
"message": "Hello Message"
},
"priority": "high"
}' \
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

but I'm receiving a 401 Unauthorized Error. What's wrong?

Comment: `registration_ids` are the device_id whom you want to send the notification not your project number

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521459/gcm-http-401-authorization-error

Comment: I want to send to all devices

Comment: Send registeration id's of all the devices as an array

Answer (score 1):

registration_ids is an array of device identifiers, not the project number.

If you want to send to all devices without capturing the device id, you could register them to a specific topic. e.g. : topic/foo.

As for how to push a notification via FCM
Your HTTP body should be structured like this.

{
  "to": "/topics/foo",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
   }
}

For more information:
Google documentation page : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging