# Enabling Oauth2sso on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to get spring security oauth2 setup on my application in Google app engine.  Everything seems to work fine locally but when i deploy to app engine things start to break down.  After I authenticate through google its forwarding me to a Whitelabel error page.  In the console I see this error:

```
http://my-application.appspot.com/login?state=t…m&session_state=8b67f5df659a8324430803973b9e1726e39fd454..1ae3&prompt=none 
401 (Unauthorized)
```

I setup my auth with this application.yml file:

```
security:
  oauth2:
client:
  clientId: client-key
  clientSecret: secret-key
  accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
  userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
  clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  scope:
    - openid
    - email
    - profile
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
resource:
  userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
  preferTokenInfo: true
```

My security config looks somethign like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

I have configured the Oauth ID on the google credential pages to allow authorized javascript origins to be:

```
http://my-application.appspot.com
https://my-application.appspot.com
http://localhost:8080
```

And the authorized redirect URIs to:

```
http://my-application.appspot.com/login
https://my-application.appspot.com/login
http://localhost:8080/login
```

Any ideas why i might be getting unauthorized errors once I deploy to GAE?

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Are you sure that the user you are trying to authenticate with has the "ROLE_ADMIN" authority?

Comment: Positive.  I have tried stripping that out and leaving it with just oauth authentication on all pages and it still gives the same error.

Comment: If possible, can you share a minimal, reproducible sample project on GitHub?

Comment: I was able to resolve this.  Turns out it had to do with the app.yaml file (which I unfortunately did not post here). The issue seems to be with spring security and running an application on multiple instances.  It seemed like the security was not being passed between instances when it was trying to load js libraries and other resources.  Have yet to research how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is about Authorization, maybe missed step on fully authorizing application, such as moving your client_secret.json to your working directory.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

**Step 1: Turn on the Drive API**

1. Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google
   Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click
   Continue, then Go to credentials. On the Add credentials to your
   project page, click the Cancel button.

   2. At the top of the page, select the OAuth consent screen tab. Select
      an Email address, enter a Product name if not already set, and click
      the Save button. Select the Credentials tab, click the Create
      credentials button and select OAuth client ID.
   3. Select the application type Other, enter the name "Drive API
      Quickstart", and click the Create button.
   4. Click OK to dismiss the resulting dialog.
   5. Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the
      client ID.
   6. Move this file to your working directory and rename it
      client_secret.json.

helpful link :
[GCM http 401 authorization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521459/gcm-http-401-authorization-error/21457262#21457262)

Comment: This was resolved by only using one instance. It SEEMS the authentication isn't passing across servers.  Havent had a chance to look into that yet.