# how to do push notification from android from php

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

hi iam trying to send notification from my php web server to android mobile...but i am getting response as

```
Unauthorized Error 401
```

below is my code

```
<?php $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$device_ids = array('devise ID' );
$headers = array('Authorization: key=api key',
'Content-Type: application/json');
$t_data = array();
$t_data['message'] = array('Someone commented on your business.');
$t_json = array( 'registration_ids' => $device_ids , 'data' => $t_data );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $t_json ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE)
{
 die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

how can i resolve this error

Comment: double check `API key` .

Comment: ya i checked it but no luck

Comment: Have you defined api key .. "Authorization: key=api key". This api key is issued when app is been registered on Google for GCM services. Check this.

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619759/google-gcm-server-returns-unauthorized-error-401

Answer (score 1):

this is the working script which i have implemented in my own GCM project. Try to run this.
Make sure to do changes in the "api_key" and "registrationids".

```
 <?php
        $api_key = "AIzBpx4XbXkhkjwKd8P-v2d1Jk";
        $registrationIDs = array("APA91bjkj3Rjlo8T_URx15NqvxY2mRyQ");
        $message = "congratulations";
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                    'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                    );

        $headers = array(
                        'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
                        'Content-Type: application/json');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
    ?>
```