# 401 Unauthorized error in Android GCM , GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I had recently changed changed my **GCM php api for Json** from dev to **Google App Engine**,The service works in my server and i tried over **GAE** i got **Unauthorized 401** error.

I changed Browser key also several times from different accounts. What problem it should be, How can i get rid from this error...

[Similar Problem link..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520595/gcm-http-error-401-unauthorized)

Comment: Do you mind to some code snippets?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/