# unauthorized in the gcm

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

`CURL --header "Authorization: key=XXXXXXXXX" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"XXXXXXXX\"]}"`

this is my request, 
im trying to send this from my cmd,
with the api key i created in google console with my endpoint as registration_ids.

but this is what i get :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

any ideas ?
thx :)

Comment: Have you added the IP to the authorized hosts?

Comment: Where do i need to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14135686/4414875

Comment: Google changed the console. So there is any new link to edit the ips ?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<project-name>`

then pick the server key you created. At the bottom of the page you could add whitelisted IP's/ranges.

Comment: I have api key and not server key. I put in the Key restriction my ip and its still the same error

Comment: The payload field is empty in the sent JSON? The changes there are not immedately synchronized, it took several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `401 Unauthorized` because GCM is only accepting requests from HTTPS-based hosts, which your local console is not.

The easiest way to verify this (if you don't already have HTTPS-based website) is:

**STAGE 1** - getting HTTPS-enabled website

1. Create account on CloudFlare
2. Change your domain's DNS to CloudFlare's
3. Enter your server's IP in CloudFlare console
4. Enable free HTTPS (and disable cache - it may be tricky sometimes)

Now traffic to your website will be redirected through CloudFlare. 
Traffic from your clients to CloudFlare will be encrypted, and traffic from CloudFlare to your server won't.

While it's not 100% secure, it allows to secure most common vector of attack - malicious internet provider etc and it takes very little effort to get free service worker-ready website.

If you want your own cert, you can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

**STAGE 2** - putting GCM sender on your HTTPS server

I have example code for you in PHP:

```
<?

function sendPushNotification($data, $ids)
{
    echo("<br><br><b>Sending notifications...</b>");
    // Insert real GCM API key from the Google APIs Console
    $apiKey = 'AIza...';
    // Set POST request body
    $post = array(
      'registration_ids'  => $ids,
      'data'              => $data,
    );
    // Set CURL request headers
    $headers = array(
      'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Initialize curl handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set URL to GCM push endpoint
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
    // Set request method to POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // Set custom request headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    // Get the response back as string instead of printing it
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set JSON post data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
    // Actually send the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // Handle errors
    if (curl_errno($ch))
    {
      echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    // Close curl handle
    curl_close($ch);
    // Debug GCM response
    echo $result;
}


$data = array('message' => 'JAAAREEEEK!');
// Please note that currently push payload is not supported. However if you're reading this answer from the future it might work

// The recipient registration tokens for this notification
// https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/
$ids = ['registrationid1','registrationid2']

// Send push notification via Google Cloud Messaging
sendPushNotification($data, $ids);
```

I had exactly the same problem and this solution solved it. If you'll have any further problems, please give me a shout.